# Bootstrap Glyphicons and style scoped

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'm making a web app using AngularJS and x-editable. I have a huge external CSS file I have to use and can't modify. X-editable uses Bootstrap so Bootstrap styles need to be imported too.

When I imported the Bootstrap styles normally, my page layout broke but Glyphicon icons worked fine.

When I used style scope attribute, my page layout was fine but Glyphicon icons didn't work. I wonder what would be causing this.

This is the part where I want to use the Bootstrap styles:

```
<div id="infoMsg" ng-controller="InfoMsgCtrl">
  <style scoped>
    @import "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";
  </style>
  <a href="#" editable-textarea="infoMsg" e-rows="7" e-cols="40">
    <pre>{{ infoMsg || 'empty' }}</pre>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: We have no way to know what the problem is. for example, in what way did your page break? What's in your custom CSS? Why don't the Glyphicons work?

Comment: Did you include the `glyphicons-halflings-regular` fonts in your project?

Comment: For some reason, I thought that importing the CSS on the web would also use fonts on a cloud somewhere. This is probably a problem with the fonts location on my server.

Answer (score 0):

You using html layouts from http://getbootstrap.com ??? If so they changed the version to 3.3.5 updating should fix your errors.
Without your html i can't be 100% sure about this.